# Won't add 8th library

Tags: android, eclipse, static-libraries

Eclipse is seemingly having intense difficulties adding** 8 libraries to my project. Is there an unspoken maximum of 7 libraries per project that I haven't heard of?

I am getting issues saying that the compiler "Could not find class ***"

An example is this:

favorite
I have a project that runs perfectly fine on newer devices and API levels, however, I'm getting some issues on emulators. When I load up the application on an emulator, I get this issue:

```
02-22 18:36:11.584: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 872 (Lcom/google/zxing/WriterException;)
02-22 18:36:11.584: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x7da
02-22 18:36:11.584: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY:  rejected Lcom/example/myapp/Card;.getFrontView (Landroid/content/Context;)Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;
02-22 18:36:11.584: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x07da
02-22 18:36:11.584: W/dalvikvm(652): VFY:  rejected Lcom/example/myapp/Card;.getFrontView (Landroid/content/Context;)Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;
02-22 18:36:11.584: W/dalvikvm(652): Verifier rejected class Lcom/example/myapp/Card;
```

At first I thought it may have been either my library or how I was adding** it, but I've recently cleared*** all of my libraries and readded them and I'm getting the same issues on a different library.

```
02-25 21:03:45.379: E/dalvikvm(12018): Could not find class 'org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator', referenced from method com.example.myapp.Card
02-25 21:03:45.379: W/dalvikvm(12018): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1054 (Lorg/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator;) in Lcom/example/myapp/Card;
```

These errors mean that the project doesn't have proper access to my library's classes, right? But why is the error inconsistent for which library it is? I've tried removing*** and readding the libraries the exact same way that the other libraries were added, but there's no luck on library #8.

What do I do?

** Adding: I've tried adding the libraries to a User Library (includes all of the existing documents that I have) and just simply copying the .jar to the libs folder.

*** Removing: To get rid of the library, if it is inside a User Library, I will edit my User Library containing the .jar I'm looking to remove and use the "remove" option. Otherwise, I will simply right click and "delete" the library from the libs directory.

As for a ["User Library"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acN9K.png)

Comment: "I've tried removing and readding the libraries the exact same way that the other libraries were added" -- if you mean anything other than "copied the JARs into `libs/`" or perhaps "added them as Android Library Projects", then probably you're doing it wrong. IOW, you may wish to explain precisely what "removing and readding the libraries the exact same way that the other libraries were added" means in your case.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the concern, however I have attempted adding them in both ways you've mentioned. I've also edited my post to reflect that. If that weren't the case, however, why would my first 7 libraries work without fail?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by "User Library". But I am not aware of a limitation on the number of JARs in `libs/`, let alone a magic cutoff at 7.

Comment: @CommonsWare Please check the edit for what a "User Library" is

Comment: "User Library" is not an Android build tool construct. I would not use one in an Android project. JARs go in `libs/`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Well, regardless, it doesn't resolve the issue. The reason I like User Libraries is because I use a set of libraries in nearly every application and it allows me to add them all with ease.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25098/discussion-between-rileye-and-commonsware)